# Cosmo db taking too long to do simple lookup queries

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmo db which I am using for a simple lookup. the database has 1.5 k records . While testing with 300 queries for lookups on a local mongo instance it takes around 200 milliseconds.

When I push the same code into an Azure function and connect it with cosmo database, it takes 3-4 seconds to do the same 300 lookups even though the Azure function and cosmo are in the same region.

I am using connection pooling, and async functions to parallelise the queries.

```
function lookup(x) {
    const collection = this.client.db().collection('StudentTable');
    const res = await collection.findOne({id:x.id, class:x.class} as FindOptions<Document>, { sort: { $natural: -1 } });
    return res
} 

Promise.all(arr.map(async x => {
    return lookup(x})
```

I can't merge these lookups using 'in' cause, I also need to find if a record is unable to lookup. Any idea why there's such a huge performance difference and also how to improve it?

Comment: Please edit to provide more details. For example: Are you seeing any throttling, due to insufficient RU/sec? Did you set up an index on `class`? As written, there's really not enough info to go on.

Comment: Also: how are you doing your 300 lookups? All at once, from a single Azure Function instantiation, or 300 separate Azure Function instantiations? If it's the latter, I suspect your delays are caused by making calls to Azure Functions, unrelated to Cosmos DB.